# Upgrading Hugo to latest version broke Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, hugo

I know this answer has somewhat been answered, but the answer doesn't solve my problem, hence my question.

We have a website, using until recently Hugo and Google Analytics. It worked fine, and here is the code that worked fine:

```
baseurl: "https://XXXXXX.com/"
languageCode: "en-us"
title: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
theme: XXXXXXXX-hugo-theme
MetaDataFormat: "yaml"
pluralizelisttitles: false
permalinks:
  blog: /blog/:year/:month/:slug
params:
  googleAnalyticsID: "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
```

We were using Hugo version 0.21. After we upgraded to Hugo 0.48, the GA stopped working. I don't know what is wrong. If you inspect the website, you won't find the script, but the script is there for my code.

Can anyone give me some advice. Also, another detail, our GA key is being injected when building for production, via a Jenkins job. Don't know if this helps, but before the upgrade we didn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your templates to make sure you've included the GA templates and the params are correct? Example from the documentation: https://gohugo.io/templates/internal/#configure-google-analytics

Comment: I don't really get it man. Do I just state the Google template in the head of my index.html. I am a beginner at Hugo. Please help. This documentation is not very helpful. Please provide instructions if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `params:` and `ID` from `googleAnalyticsID`. So that it only has:

> `googleAnalytics: UA-XXXXXXXX-X`

Or

> `googleAnalytics = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"`